# It it possible to update specific directory to old revision in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I tried to update some files to old revision in many ways, but I haven't found yet.
(not permanently, just temporarily updating for testing)

For example, the following is OK in SVN.

```
svn up -r 100 foo.cpp
U    foo.cpp
```

But in Mercurial, 'up' command doesn't permit file name argument.

Only is it possible to update entire source tree in Mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally disallowed by Mercurial and other DVCSs.  Both CVS and Subversion track which revision you have checked out on a per-file basis.  You could have r1 of file x and r2 of file y.  In a DVCs the entire repository is at a single version, which in Mercurial you can see with `hg id`.

As @Tom points out you can have modified files from different revisions, but if you want to see another revision without changes showing up you need to do the `update` in another clone (which given that local clones use hard links to be (a) instant and (b) space efficient) that's not much of a hassle.

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to use `hg revert`:

```
hg revert -r 100 foo.cpp
```

Note that this gives you local changes, as can be seen by running `hg diff`.

See `hg help revert` for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but it's different from what I want... Is it an only way?

Comment: What is the problem with using ``revert``?